# Multi choice, easygui buttonbox

Tags: python, if-statement, random, easygui

We trying to create a multi choice menu using easygui, buttonbox.
We have tired ***if, else* and *elif*** statements but whenever selecting one of the math subject options, it always takes the player to addition/will ask the player addition questions.
We are not sure whether it is a problem with the if/else/elif statment *(we would've expected elif to work)* or if it is another problem with the Figure1/Figure2 we can not seem to find.

Here is an example of our coding, we have only shown you the subject selection menu, addition, and subtraction problems. *(to hopefully save you all time as all the subjects are the same, they are just be changed to DivisionAnswers and MultiplicationAnswers etc. )* **But we are focusing on the problem within the subject selection**

```
   Subject = easygui.buttonbox ("What maths subject would you like to test?", choices = ["Addition","Subtraction","Multiplication","Division"])
if "Addition":
    easygui.msgbox ("Please enter the correct answer to earn a point, there are 10 questions in this quiz")

for number in range(0,10):
    Figure1 = random.randrange(0,11)
    Figure2 = random.randrange(0,11)

    PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is " +str(Figure1)+ " + " +str(Figure2)+ "?")

    if int(PlayerAnswer) == Figure1 + Figure2:
        AdditionAnswers += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is "+str(AdditionAnswers))
        print(AdditionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked
    else:
        AdditionAnswers += 0
        IncorrectAnswers += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry, incorrect! Your score is still "+str(AdditionAnswers))
        print(AdditionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked

easygui.msgbox ("You scored " +str(AdditionAnswers)+ " out of 10")

print(AdditionAnswers) #To check if programme is calculating score correctly
print(IncorrectAnswers)

elif "Subtraction":
    easygui.msgbox ("Please enter the correct answer to earn a point, there are 10 questions in this quiz")

for number in range(0,10):
    Figure1 = random.randrange(0,11)
    Figure2 = random.randrange(0,11)

    PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is " +str(Figure1)+ " - " +str(Figure2)+ "?")

    if int(PlayerAnswer) == Figure1 - Figure2:
        SubtractionAnswers += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is "+str(SubtractionAnswers))
        print(SubtractionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked
    else:
        SubtractionAnswers+= 0
        IncorrectAnswers += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry, incorrect! Your score is still "+str(SubtractionAnswers))
        print(SubtractionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked

easygui.msgbox ("You scored " +str(SubtractionAnswers)+ " out of 10")

print(SubtractionAnswers) #To check if programme is calculating score correctly
print(IncorrectAnswers)
```

Thankyou for any help or suggestions you can give us, it is greatly appreciated as we are all just beginning to learn python programming.

EDIT ~
It seems to bypass all of the other subjects and head straight to addition regardless of what subject is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if/elifs seems to be ok. The comparison is wrong. Should be:

```
if Subject == "Addition":
```

You are after all storing your choice from the buttonbox in a variable called `Subject`

Apply the same for the rest. Good luck !
PS. the general concept is to name variables with a lowercase. Uppercase is in a way reserved for classes.
EDIT: Fixed the code for you. Massive indentation errors.

```
import easygui
import random
AdditionAnswers = 0
IncorrectAnswers = 0
SubtractionAnswers = 0
Subject = easygui.buttonbox ("What maths subject would you like to test?", choices = ["Addition","Subtraction","Multiplication","Division"])
if Subject == "Addition":
    easygui.msgbox ("Please enter the correct answer to earn a point,there are 10 questions in this quiz")
    for number in range(0,10):
        Figure1 = random.randrange(0,11)
        Figure2 = random.randrange(0,11)
        PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is " +str(Figure1)+ " + " +str(Figure2)+ "?")
        if int(PlayerAnswer) == Figure1 + Figure2:
            AdditionAnswers += 1
            easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is "+str(AdditionAnswers))
            print(AdditionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked
        else:
            AdditionAnswers += 0
            IncorrectAnswers += 1
            easygui.msgbox ("Sorry, incorrect! Your score is still "+str(AdditionAnswers))
        print(AdditionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked

    easygui.msgbox ("You scored " +str(AdditionAnswers)+ " out of 10")
    print(AdditionAnswers) #To check if programme is calculating score correctly
    print(IncorrectAnswers)

elif Subject == "Subtraction":
    easygui.msgbox ("Please enter the correct answer to earn a point, there are 10 questions in this quiz")
    for number in range(0,10):
        Figure1 = random.randrange(0,11)
        Figure2 = random.randrange(0,11)
        PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is " +str(Figure1)+ " - " +str(Figure2)+ "?")

        if int(PlayerAnswer) == Figure1 - Figure2:
            SubtractionAnswers += 1
            easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is "+str(SubtractionAnswers))
            print(SubtractionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked
        else:
            SubtractionAnswers+= 0
            IncorrectAnswers += 1
            easygui.msgbox ("Sorry, incorrect! Your score is still "+str(SubtractionAnswers))
            print(SubtractionAnswers)#To see if game is keeping count of questions asked

    easygui.msgbox ("You scored " +str(SubtractionAnswers)+ " out of 10")
    print(SubtractionAnswers) #To check if programme is calculating score correctly
    print(IncorrectAnswers)
```

Comment: I did that for all, but it still asks us addition questions when we click on other subjects
*edit*
It seems to bypass all of the other subjects and goes straight to addition regardless of what subject is selected

Comment: just edited my answer. your indentations were ALL over the place

Comment: Ops thankyou so much! (sounds like me, I'm too lazy or totally forget to indent properly half the time!) Thankyou so so much for your help, it means a lot!

Comment: Consider using an IDE like PyCharm for example. It will show you syntax errors as you type. Good luck.

Comment: Works great now! Thankyou so much Damian!